# ESC POS cut adding margin on top

Tags: receipt, pos

I am using c# raw printer to send ESC pos commands to impact printer. When i use GS     V 65 command it is adding margin on the top for next print any idea how to remove feed after cut?

Comment: hi, you got the solution? i am facing same issue,i am implementing in Android. After 1st print it is adding top margin for second print.

Comment: Yes if printer supports reverse feed send reverse feed command.

Comment: what is reverse feed command? can you explain more or share some piece of code or something.thanks in advance